# add new column to pandas DataFrame with value depended on previous row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have an existing pandas DataFrame, and I want to add a new column, where the value of each row will depend on the previous row.
for example:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(4, 4)), columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])

df1
Out[31]: 
   a  b  c  d
0  9  3  3  0
1  3  9  5  1
2  1  7  5  6
3  8  0  1  7
```

and now I want to create column e, where for each row i the value of df1['e'][i] would be: `df1['e'][i] = df1['d'][i] - df1['d'][i-1]`

desired output:

```
df1:
   a  b  c  d  e
0  9  3  3  0  0
1  3  9  5  1  1
2  1  7  5  6  5
3  8  0  1  7  1
```

how can I achieve this?

Comment: If my answer was helpful, don't forget `accept` it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`sub`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.sub.html) with [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html):

```
df['e'] = df.d.sub(df.d.shift(), fill_value=0)
print (df)
   a  b  c  d    e
0  9  3  3  0  0.0
1  3  9  5  1  1.0
2  1  7  5  6  5.0
3  8  0  1  7  1.0
```

If need convert to `int`:

```
df['e'] = df.d.sub(df.d.shift(), fill_value=0).astype(int)
print (df)
   a  b  c  d  e
0  9  3  3  0  0
1  3  9  5  1  1
2  1  7  5  6  5
3  8  0  1  7  1
```